# If I need to unload data and copy data between 2 Redshift clusters, what is the best approach to script the process?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have done migration data between Amazon Redshift clusters using unload/copy commands via s3 interactively.  The next step is to automate the process and I'm looking for best approach to do so.

Answer (score 2):

you can use java/ any other language to below steps and automate

1) connect to cluster 1

2) unload data to amazon s3

3) connect to cluster 2

4) copy data from amazon s3 to redshift cluster

you can use shell script or php or simple java program will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the two ways that you can try:

1. Use python or bash script to unload and copy data from one RedShift
   cluster to another. In this approach the staging area will be S3. If
   you are trying to unload and copy between separate accounts then you
   need to have appropriate IAM Roles and trust policies. This can be a
   little challenging. You can automate this process by using **AWS Data Pipeline**.
2. Take a **snapshot and restore a RedShift cluster** using the snapshot. Also if you want to share this snapshot to other account then just go to Manage Access and put the Account ID of the destination RedShift Cluster. This is very simple and no need to write any code.